# Find and replace url in substring from html tags in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have tried a lot, but with no success. I have a column **content** (longtext) stored in a database.So, I wanna find all occurrences of **https://curious-api.example.pro** and replace it with **http://localhost**. Thanks in advance. Here is the content:

```html
<section id="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(https://curious-api.example.pro/fixture-images/images/label_appointment_scheduling.jpg);">

</section>

<section id="solutions-article">
    <div id="" class="content-aside-image img-left">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col col-12 col-md-6 image">
                <figure><img src="https://curious-api.example.pro/fixture-images/images/as_what_we_do.jpg" width="100%" alt="car" /></figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-12 col-md-6 content">
                <p>Curious Inc helpt u en uw bedrijf om uw planning te optimaliseren. Wij bieden uw medewerkers en uw klanten de mogelijkheid om uw agenda’s in te zien en desgewenst zelf te plannen. Wij koppelen de planning aan uw dienstverlening. Communicatie met uw klanten over de agenda en uw dienstverlening verloopt eenvoudiger, u integreert moeiteloos uw planning aan uw boekhouding en met slimme rapportages optimaliseert u uw processen. </p>
                </div</div>
            </div>
</section>
<section id="solution-showcases">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card basic transparent disable-hover">
                <div class="card-inner">
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="https://curious-api.example.pro/fixture-images/images/CUR 003 Iconen labels_Agenda Planning.svg" alt="1" /></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Slim plannen in de agenda</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Ga slimmer om met vrije momenten. Krijg inzage in de agenda op mobiele telefoon, tablet en PC, plan sneller door automatische controle op beschikbaarheid van mens en middelen.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card basic transparent disable-hover">
                <div class="card-inner">
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="https://curious-api.example.pro/fixture-images/images/CUR 003 Iconen labels_Communicatie.svg" alt="2" /></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Klantbeheer en communicatie</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Verbeter uw service en communiceer proactief over de planning en uw dienstverlening met uw klanten. Onze producten werken met app, social media, sms, e-mail en webportaal.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card basic transparent disable-hover">
                <div class="card-inner">
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="https://curious-api.example.pro/fixture-images/images/CUR 003 Iconen labels_Boekhouding.svg" alt="3" /></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Administratie en optimalisatie</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Factureer automatisch op basis van geleverde diensten, koppel met uw boekhoudpakket en verkrijg rapportages die u helpen om nog slimmer te werken.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="section-customer-stories">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <figure class="customer-image"><img src="https://curious-api.example.pro/fixture-images/images/sander_borsten.png" alt="" /></figure>
                <figure class="customer-logo"><img src="https://curious-api.example.pro/fixture-images/images/logo_anwb.jpg" height="65" alt="" /></figure>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: your `mysql` version?

Comment: Does the replace() function not do what you want?

Comment: Always Sunny, thanks for showing interest. Here is my mysql version: 5.7.25

Comment: @Capfer have a look on my given answer.

Comment: saritonin, replace() function did not help. This is what I tried: SELECT content FROM solution WHERE content REGEXP "(https?:\/\/|www\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}";

SELECT content FROM solution WHERE content REGEXP "^(https?:\/\/|www\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}";

SELECT S.content, REPLACE(S.content, @find_string, @replace_with_host) as result FROM `solution` S WHERE content LIKE '%' || @find_string || '%';

Comment: @Capfer make a try on this function https://gist.github.com/crx4/a9fc379d4e833fc03918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about MYSQL [replace()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) **?**

```
UPDATE your_tbl_name SET content = REPLACE(content,'https://curious-api.example.pro','http://localhost')
```

You can also speed up things with a **(optional)** WHERE clause e.g

```
UPDATE your_tbl_name SET content = REPLACE(content,'https://curious-api.example.pro','http://localhost') WHERE content LIKE '%https://curious-api.example.pro%'
```

**If you want regex replace on mysql 5.7**, you can try this: https://gist.github.com/crx4/a9fc379d4e833fc03918

Answer (score 0):

Use [`replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE table_name SET content = REPLACE(content, 'https://curious-api.example.pro', 'http://localhost')
```

Comment: Always Sunny, now everything is working. I had had the like cause. I removed it and everithing is ok now. Thanks a lot